# activescaffold: no response when clicking search, create, edit, show

Tags: ruby, rubygems, crud, activescaffold

I'm using activescaffold to display my models, 
model list can be displayed correctly,
but the problem is: there is no response when I click search, create, edit, show. But "delete" works well.

Does anyone know the reason?

my rails version =>
The bundle currently has rails locked at 3.0.9

ruby version =>
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]

OS =>
windows xp x86

and from the log I can see the html.erb rendered without any problem:

```
Rendered c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/active_scaffold-3.0.23/frontends/default/views/_form_attribute.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/active_scaffold-3.0.23/frontends/default/views/_form_attribute.html.erb (0.0ms)
  [1m[35mDepartment Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `departments`.* FROM `departments` WHERE `departments`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mDepartment Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `departments`.* FROM `departments`[0m
Rendered c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/active_scaffold-3.0.23/frontends/default/views/_form_attribute.html.erb (31.2ms)
  [1m[35mRole Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles` WHERE `roles`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mRole Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`[0m
Rendered c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/active_scaffold-3.0.23/frontends/default/views/_form_attribute.html.erb (15.6ms)
Rendered c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/active_scaffold-3.0.23/frontends/default/views/_form.html.erb (484.4ms)
Rendered c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/active_scaffold-3.0.23/frontends/default/views/_base_form.html.erb (531.2ms)
Rendered c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/active_scaffold-3.0.23/frontends/default/views/_update_form.html.erb (546.9ms)
Rendered c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/active_scaffold-3.0.23/frontends/default/views/_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/active_scaffold-3.0.23/frontends/default/views/_list_inline_adapter.html.erb (15.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 969ms (Views: 31.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: If you use CanCan check https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/issues/138

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I found that in my application.js file I was only requiring jquery, jquery_ujs, and acitve_scaffold; I was missing jquery-ui

so "/app/assets/javascripts/application.js" should look like this:

```
//= require query
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require active_scaffold
//= require_tree .
```

I hope this helps, it worked for me!